# Iterator tripping Visual C++ 2017 assertion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, stl, visual-studio-2017

I have copied Mark Borgerding's [kissfft.hh](https://github.com/mborgerding/kissfft) (templated version of his FFT code) into my project and modified it to use iterators instead of pointers.  Using Xcode all is well.  When I tried to run it after compiling with Microsoft's Visual C++ 2017 I get an assertion error from the following code:

```
void transform(ComplexIterator fft_in, ComplexIterator fft_out) const
{
    ComplexIterator const Fout_beg = fft_out;
    ComplexIterator const Fout_end = fft_out + p*m;

    do{
        *fft_out = *fft_in;
        fft_in += fstride;
    }while(++fft_out != Fout_end );
    ...
```

`ComplexIterator` is a template type, and in this situation it is a vanilla `std::vector< std::complex<float> >::iterator`.  Sometimes `Fout_end` is pointing somewhere in the middle of the `std::vector`, and sometimes it is pointing one spot after the last element in the `std::vector`, exactly like `std::vector.end()`.  When it is pointing to one spot after the last element, the `while` statement causes an assertion error, because the iterator went past the last element in the vector.  It only went past by one (i.e. it was equal to `Fout_end`), but that didn't matter.

The thing is, I thought that this was standard practice for iterators.  You keep iterating until you hit "end", which is outside the `std::vector`.  I created a simple test program to check if it also tripped the assertion check.

```
std::vector<int> p(5);
for (auto it = p.begin(); it != p.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

It doesn't.  What's going on here?  Why is the FFT code tripping the assertion check?  I can get rid of the problem by switching to Release mode, then everything works great, but I want to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the assertion is from fft_out and not from fft_in? Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @n.m. Hmm, I was pretty sure it was happening on the "while" line, but maybe you're right.  I can't do it right now, but I will check tomorrow.

Comment: Your code would dereference `end()` if `fft_out` points into an empty vector.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik True, but the vector is not empty.

Comment: Post the full assert error.

Comment: @n.m. Good call on it being fft_in, not fft_out, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that @n.m. was exactly right- the problem was fft_in and not fft_out like I thought.  I unrolled the last iteration of the `do...while` loop to avoid the problem without incurring a performance cost (I think).

```
 ComplexIterator const Fout_beg = fft_out;
 ComplexIterator const Fout_end = fft_out + p*m;

 ComplexIterator const Fout_almost_end = Fout_end - 1;
 do{
     *fft_out = *fft_in;
     fft_in += fstride;
 }while (++fft_out != Fout_almost_end);
 *fft_out = *fft_in;
```